# How to use smstools in rhel7

Tags: sms, rhel7

I want to use smstools in rhel7. But I'm having trouble getting the correct rpm.
Please help.

I have tried a rpm got from internet.
When installing package fro it showing below error.

yum search shows the output.

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum search sms
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can       use subscription-manager to register.
file:///root/Downloads/smstools3-3.1.15-1.1.x86_64.rpm/repodata/repomd.xml:    [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /root/Downloads/smstools3-3.1.15-  1.1.x86_64.rpm/repodata/repomd.xml"
Trying other mirror.
=============================== N/S matched: sms  ===============================
smstools3.x86_64 : Send text messages via GSM modems

Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

But when using yum insatll getting below error

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install smstools3.x86_64
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
file:///root/Downloads/smstools3-3.1.15-1.1.x86_64.rpm/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /root/Downloads/smstools3-3.1.15-1.1.x86_64.rpm/repodata/repomd.xml"
Trying other mirror.
Nothing to do
```

My repository is like this

```
[root@localhost ~]# vim /etc/yum.repos.d/smstools3-3.1.15-1.1.x86_64.rpm.repo 

[smstools3-3.1.15-1.1.x86_64.rpm]
name=added from: smstools3-3.1.15-1.1.x86_64.rpm
baseurl=file:///root/Downloads/smstools3-3.1.15-1.1.x86_64.rpm
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
skip_if_unavailable = 1
keepcache = 0
```

Can anyone help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue.

First copied the rpm to a directory.

```
cp /root/Downloads/smstools3-3.1.15-1.1.x86_64.rpm /root/sms
```

Then create the repository again

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo=///root/sms
```

After going to the directory and executed a createrepo .

This solved my issue.